# I am having a problem building a Flutter App

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I has a build a flutter app before successfully, but I try to update the code of my flutter app because I discovered some bugs but when j try to build it I get a error about error configuring video_player Android, I try to add it as a Dependencies but still it didn't work, I also invalidate cache's too it didn't work because it also said something about Cache's, I also upgraded my flutter SDK, still it didn't work, I will attach a image under this write up.
[The error I am facing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QnRJP.jpg)

[The error I am facing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YRjoi.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Write below command in terminal to clear cache with android project path.

```
flutter pub cache clean
./gradlew clean
gradlew cleanBuildCache
```

Comment: Same error after running flutter pub cache clean

Comment: Can you add error with detail?

Comment: * What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':video_player_android'.
> Could not load compiled classes for build file 'C:\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\video_player_android-2.3.3\android\build.gradle' from cache.
> Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
   > Could not get unknown property 'android' for project ':video_player_android' of type org.gradle.api.Project.
   > Could not get unknown property 'android' for project ':video_player_android' of type org.gradle.api.Project.

Comment: The second two code is not working it is saying it is not a cmdlet

Comment: Update answer with windows commands.You need to run gradlew command with android folder.

Comment: Do i need to install gradle manually

Comment: You need to run this command in android project path. C://Projectname//android

Comment: still having that error

Comment: * Where:
Script 'C:\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\app_plugin_loader.gradle' line: 33

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating script.
> assert pluginDirectory.exists()
         |               |
         |               false
         C:\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\app_settings-4.1.6\android

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 7s